# SQL select the two values that bounds an input value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, sql

I have a table with date fields. I need to select two rows where the first row is the date just before an input date and the second row is the date just after the input date.

For example, given an input date of "10/06/2022" and the following date table:

The id is an Integer and date is a Date field. The table is an ArcGIS geodatabase table.

| **id** | **date** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 02/06/2022 |
| 2 | 05/06/2022 |
| 3 | 08/06/2022 |
| 4 | 11/06/2022 |
| 5 | 16/06/2022 |
| 6 | 18/06/2022 |
| 7 | 20/06/2022 |

I need the SQL to return two rows:

| **id** | **date** |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 08/06/2022 |
| 4 | 11/06/2022 |

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to specify the storage format of the data. ISO SQL will not work with most data formats (only enterprise geodatabase, really), so requesting SQL might not provide you a solution.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL, something like this might work, I assume that your geodatabase is installed on a SQL Server :

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 id, date FROM date_table
WHERE date < CAST('10/06/2022' as date)
ORDER BY date DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 id, date FROM date_table
WHERE date > CAST('10/06/2022' as date)
ORDER BY date
;
```